# how to extract tuple data store in dictionary with some split function

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary in which I have values stored in a tuple of list so I want to fetch those data

example:

```
dict_data = {'Name':[('Rahul.sharma','raj.kumar'),(14,16)],'class_teacher':[('Rajesh.kumar','Mohan.pal'),(43,34)]}
```

In this dictionary, i need only the 0th index with the split of the surname of each key

the output I needed:

```
dict_data = {'Name':['sharma','kumar'], 'class_teacher': ['kumar','pal'] }
```

I tried with this:

```
for val in dict_data:
    counter = dict_data[val][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
dict_data = {'Name': [('Rahul.sharma', 'raj.kumar'), (14, 16)],
             'class_teacher': [('Rajesh.kumar', 'Mohan.pal'), (43, 34)]}


def extract(val):
    return [s.split('.')[-1] for s in val[0]]


result = {key: extract(value) for key, value in dict_data.items()}

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'Name': ['sharma', 'kumar'], 'class_teacher': ['kumar', 'pal']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
dict_new = {}
for val in dict_data:
    counter = dict_data[val][0]
    list1 = []
    for count in counter:
        list1.append(count)
    dict_new = dict_new[val] = list1
```